# slideUp doesn't work with .next()

Tags: jquery

I'm target divs for `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` with `.next()` event. everything is working fine except when I click for slideUp, It goes up and then again comes down. I Want to slideToggle on click of same button.
demo **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/locateganesh/z3jxv3tz/)**

```
<div class="earnContent">toggle one</div>
<div class="content">content one</div>
<div class="earnContent">toggle two</div>
<div class="content">content tow</div>
<div class="earnContent">toggle three</div>
<div class="content">content three</div>
```

js:

```
$(".earnContent").click(function(e) {
    $(".content").slideUp(300);
    $(this).next().slideDown(300);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple:-

```
$(".earnContent").click(function (e) {
    $(".content").not($(this).next()).slideUp(300);
    $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
});
```

[**`FIDDLE DEMO`**](http://jsfiddle.net/z3jxv3tz/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Here i changes done by me:

```
$(".earnContent").click(function(e) {
    flag = ($(this).next().css('display')=='block');
    $(".content").slideUp(300);
    if(!flag)
      $(this).next().slideDown(300);
});
```

> Note: In flag i am checking if next content div is not `block` means
>   already closed then only open it otherwise don't.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/z3jxv3tz/1/)

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is the following:

```
$(".earnContent").click(function(e) {
    // Retrieve current content
    var $thisContent = $(this).next();

    // Hide any other shown content
    $(".content").not($thisContent).slideUp(300);

    // Toggle the visibility of current content
    $thisContent.slideToggle(300);
});
```

**[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/z3jxv3tz/3/)**